# (C++ ) variable initialized in constructor is being put at the end of an unrelated arrray.

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I'm new to C++, and I've spent a few hours trying to determine why the "execute.ListAllBooks()" function in main.cpp seems to be including the string assigned to the libraryName variable (which is declared in Library.h and initialized in the constructor in Library.cpp) within the array entitled "BookList". The last element of the array lists as "MyLibrary", when I expect it to be an empty string. An additional question I have is why the array seems to have 11 elements in it. I previously coded in Java, and I would expect there to be ten elements considering I initialized the array with this line "public: std::string BookList[10]". Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Library.h"   

int main() {
    Library execute("MyLibrary");
    execute.AddBook("Book 1");
    execute.AddBook("Book 2");
    execute.AddBook("Book 3");
    execute.AddBook("Book 4");
    execute.AddBook("Book 5");
    execute.AddBook("Book 6");
    execute.AddBook("Book 7");
    execute.AddBook("Book 8");
    execute.AddBook("Book 9");
    execute.AddBook("Book 10");
    execute.ListAllBooks();
    return 0;  
}
```

Library.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Library.h"

using namespace std;

Library::Library(const string &name) {
    libraryName = name;
    length = 0;
}

bool Library::AddBook(const string &name) {
    counter = 0;
    int arraySize = sizeof(BookList)/sizeof(*BookList);
    while(counter < arraySize) {
        if(BookList[counter] == name) {
            return false;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    if(length >= arraySize) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        length++;
        BookList[length - 1] = name;
        return true;
    }
}

bool Library::RemoveBook(const std::string &name) {
    counter = 0;
    while(counter < sizeof(BookList)/sizeof(*BookList)) {
        if(BookList[counter] == name) {
            BookList[counter] = "";
            length--;
            while(counter < length - 1) {
                BookList[counter] = BookList[counter + 1];
                BookList[counter + 1] = "";
                counter++;
            }
            return true;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    return false;
}

void Library::ListAllBooks() const {
    int length = sizeof(BookList);
    int counter = 0;
    while(counter < length) {
        cout << BookList[counter] + "," << endl;
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Library.h

```
#include <iostream>

#ifndef ASS1_LIBRARY_H
#define ASS1_LIBRARY_H

class Library {

    public: std::string BookList[10];
    private: std::string libraryName;
    private: int length;
    private: int counter;

    public: explicit Library(const std::string &name);

    // Add a new book,
    // return true for success, false if book already in library
    bool AddBook(const std::string &name);

    // Remove a book
    // return true for success, false if book not in library
    bool RemoveBook(const std::string &name);

    // List all books in library
    public: void ListAllBooks() const;

    // Return true if book in library, false otherwise
    bool IsInLibrary(const std::string &name) const;

};

// friend function
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Library &lib);

#endif //ASS1_LIBRARY_H
```

Comment: You're using `sizeof(BookList)` to get the number of elements in `BookList`.   That is completely incorrect.  You either need to track the number of elements in `BookList` separately, or change the type of `BookList` so it is a container (e.g. `std::vector<std::string>`) that tracks how many elements it has, then use `BookList.size()`.

Comment: Thanks for responding, good to know. I removed all instances of the sizeof method from my code, and instead created a private variable called MAX that I used to set the size of the array    *public: std::string BookList[MAX];*. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same problem though. Sorry, I'm not sure how to properly format code in comments.

Comment: Have you debugged the max value that counter becomes in `ListAllBooks`? What about the memory locations of `Library::libraryName`  `Library::BookList`?

Comment: Since my last comment I added a new method called "IsInLibrary(const std::string &name)" to compartmentalize my code. I then changed my "AddBook" method to call this method to do the work of checking if the book already exists in the array. I'm not sure why, but somehow that resolved the issue. The "ListAllBooks()" method now lists ten elements and there is no eleventh element called "MyLibrary".

Answer (score 1):

The line `int length = sizeof(BookList);` is incorrect.

[`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) returns the number of bytes an object takes to store in memory. It just so happens that the size of `Libary` is 11. When `BookList[11]` is accessed you are overflowing the array and reading the next string in memory which is `libraryName` because of the order they were defined in your class.

You could change you class definition to:

```
 class Library {
      public: std::string BookList[10];
      public: std::string hello "Hello";
      ...
```

And accessing `BookList[11]` would result in `Hello`.

It looks like you are already calculating the correct `length` in `AddBook` so deleting the line `int length = sizeof(BookList);` all togethor should fix your problem.

On a somewhat related note, you might look into using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) to help prevent erros like this in the future.

Comment: "And accessing `BookList[11]` would result in `Hello`"... maybe. This is undefined territory and anything could result of that access.

Comment: True. It depends on the compiler but in most cases most compilers would structure classes in the way described in my answer. And that appears to be what OP's compiler is doing since they are seeing the value in `libraryName` being printed.

Comment: Definitely worth noting that it is not C++ behavior though. More like a by product of the implementation of C++